# Changing text on page based Select list selection and Query data without reloading page

Tags: jquery, select, coldfusion

I have a Select list on my page, and based on which item is selected (each item is a part number), the text on the page that describes the part's dimensions should change. Each part's dimensions (Diameter, Height) are in a db. I'm calling the query using cfquery.

The values in the Select list are the part numbers in my query. I guess what I'm having trouble with is getting the info I need from the query without reloading the page.

I'm looking for a way to say "I clicked 'Option 2'. Get the Diameter and Height for 'Option 2' from my query, and put those dimensions in my P tag."

I think JQuery could update the text just fine once I have the new dimensions, but I'm not sure how to get the dimensions I need without reloading. Thanks for your help!

Comment: seems like you're new to doing Ajax, try cfselect, bind cfdiv or 2x cfinput to a remote CFC using cfselect value as param also works (for CF8 or above)

Comment: Henry, I tried your method. The cfdiv does not update when the cfselect is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this figured out. I'm using:

```
$('#foo').change(function () {
    $.get('getInfo.cfm', function (data) { $('#output').text(data) });
});
```

And in my CFM I have my return data in cfoutput brackets. Works like a charm! Thanks for your help and suggestions, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two options.  Both involve JavaScript.

The first is to store all the data in a big JS array.  When the select box's selected item changes, that item is used to find the appropriate item in the array and display it in the appropriate div (or whatever).

The second option is similar, but instead of using a local copy of the list, you use AJAX to pull the text from a CFC on your server.

I would use the second option if there are more than a few choices.  The first option renders the page more slowly (more items, slower loading) but will respond to the change more quickly.  The AJAX option will do the initial page render more quickly, but you'll have to wait for a server trip for the displayed text.  Note that with the AJAX option, you can have the user performing other operations while the text is loading.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ben's second option.  I have an application that has two drop down menus one menu gets populated by the returned data from the query that is called by the first menu.

I suggest checking out jQuery as it is a little bit easier to work with:
[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

The call to the ColdFusion page should return a string.  Here is an example of jQuery I used:

```
$('#menu1').change(function() {

    <!-- Get the value of the dropdown menu -->    
    var selected = { menu1:$(this) .val()}       


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "the CFM file name",
            dataType: "json",              
            data: selected,
            success: function(response){                  

                <!-- if the response from the database is null set the result to "nothing found", else set it to the response -->
                if (response != "") {                       
                         $("#output").append(response);                                                 




                } else {
                   $("#output").append("nothing found");  
                }                                            

            }//end the success function

        });// end ajax call        

});    //end menu1 change function
```

I modified my code to make it (hopefully) easier to understand.  I hope this helps.